# Does the fact that $\cos(x)$ maps $[0,\pi]$ to $[-1,1]$ mean that $\cos(0) =-1$?

Tags: trigonometry

$\cos(x)$ is bijective within $[0,\pi]$, but the function tells that
$[0,\pi] \to [-1,1]$.

How is this possible? How can $\cos(0) = -1$?

Comment: Not following you.  The function $f(x)=-x$ is bijective from $[-1,1]\to [-1,1]$ but this doesn't mean that $f(-1)=-1$.

Comment: Cosine is *decreasing*  on this interval.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos : [0, \pi] \to [-1,1]$ means that $\cos$ takes an $x\in [0, \pi]$ and returns $\cos x \in [-1,1]$. It is convention to denote intervals in increasing order.